# TypeError: this.setState.myItems is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, typeerror

Im pretty sure the code is correct but i still get an error 
"TypeError: this.setState.myItems is undefined"
when i press the remove button
I tried to remove the specific item using the setState in filter() method 
It says the error is at line 35 : 
const filteredItems = this.setState.myItems.filter(myItem => {

over there

```
    import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { returnStatement, isTemplateElement } from "@babel/types";
    import "./style.css";

    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    myItems: ["Poco F1", "OnePlus 6", "MiA1", "S7 Edge"]
    };
      }

    addItem(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const { myItems } = this.state;
const newItem = this.newItem.value;
const exists = myItems.includes(newItem);

if (exists) {
  this.setState({
    message: "This Phone is already listed"
  });
} else {
  newItem !== "" &&
    this.setState({
      myItems: [...this.state.myItems, newItem]
    });
}

this.newForm.reset();
  }

    removeItem(item) {
const filteredItems = this.setState.myItems.filter(myItem => {
  return myItem !== item;
});

     this.setState({
        myItems: [...filteredItems]
      });
      }

       render() {
        const { myItems, message } = this.state;
        return (
        <div>
    <h1>
      <b>PHONE LIST</b>
    </h1>
    <form
      ref={input => (this.newForm = input)}
      onSubmit={e => this.addItem(e)}
    >
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="newItemInput">
          {" "}
          ADD NEW PHONE
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={input => (this.newItem = input)}
          placeholder="Enter Phone Name"
          className="form-control"
          id="newItemInput"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">ADD</button>
    </form>
    <div className="content">
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Phone Name</th>
            <th>add/remove</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {myItems.map(item => {
            return (
              <tr key={item}>
                <td scope="row">1</td>
                <td>{item}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={e => this.removeItem(item)}
                    type="button"
                  >
                    REMOVE
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
          <ol />
         </div>
        );
         }
          }

      export default App;
```

I want to remove the specific item using the setState in filter() method

Comment: it should be `this.state.myItems` instead of `this.setState.myItems`

Comment: `setState` is a function. You probably want `state`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `this.setState.myItems` to `this.state.myItems`

Comment: It totally worked dude. I was dumb to filter a setState though :joy:   . Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.myItems` instead of `this.setState.myItems` :)

Comment: It totally worked dude. I was dumb to filter a setState though. Thanks dude